# SQL - select rows until aggregate is matched

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregates

I have a table of packages. Each packages has a priority and weight:

```
priority | weight
-----------------
1         4
2         3
3         5
4         1
5         3
```

I want to fit all packages, sorted by priority, into a box, until the maximum allowed weight of the box is reached. For example, If I have a box of maximum allowed weight 10, I pick the following two packages:

```
priority | weight
-----------------
1         4
2         3
```

In SQL words, I want to keep `select * from package order by priority` as long as `sum(weight) <= 10`.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL 9.x?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Utsav I am going to use PostgreSQL 9.x. I'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `sum` with `order by` clause to calculate cumulative sum of weight in the order of priority and filter on that.

```
select priority, weight
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(weight) over (
            order by priority
            ) as cuml_weight
    from your_table t
    ) t
where cuml_weight <= 10;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/ZLHI31984)

As asked by OP, this can also be done using correlated subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        (
            select sum(weight)
            from your_table t2
            where t2.priority <= t.priority
            ) as cuml_weight
    from your_table t
    ) t
where cuml_weight <= 10;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MNE76061)

Comment: Is this also possible without window functions?

Comment: @JakeP. - Updated the answer. See the second one. I am just curious - why not window functions?

Comment: Interesting. Filtering on `where t2.priority <= t.priority` is clever, I did not think about that. I'll study window functions also!